# JQuery Validate programmatically

Tags: jquery, validation

I've got a list of checkboxes, next to them are two textboxes, I'm trying to validate these two textboxes only if their respective checkbox is ticked. There could be up to 100 so I don't want to write this out for all 100, is there a neater way of doing this, I guess I can't really use a wildcard as the validation only needs to kick in when the TransferModelViews index of the checkbox matches the index of the FlightNo & StartDate text fields

```
"TransferModelViews[0].TransferOptions[0].StartDate": {
    required: function () {
        return $("[name='TransferModelViews[0].TransferOptions[0].TransferSelected']").is(':checked')
    }
},
"TransferModelViews[0].TransferOptions[0].FlightNo": {
    required: function () {
        return $("[name='TransferModelViews[0].TransferOptions[0].TransferSelected']").is(':checked')
    }
},
"TransferModelViews[1].TransferOptions[0].StartDate": {
    required: function () {
        return $("[name='TransferModelViews[1].TransferOptions[0].TransferSelected']").is(':checked')
    }
},
"TransferModelViews[1].TransferOptions[0].FlightNo": {
    required: function () {
        return $("[name='TransferModelViews[1].TransferOptions[0].TransferSelected']").is(':checked')
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question

```
 $("[name*='TransferSelected']").change(function () {

        $("#bookingholiday").validate();

        var indexStr = $(this).attr('myval');

        if ($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("[name='TransferModelViews[" + indexStr + "].TransferOptions[0].StartDate']").rules("add", { required: true });
            $("[name='TransferModelViews[" + indexStr + "].TransferOptions[0].FlightNo']").rules("add", { required: true });
        }
        else {
            $("[name='TransferModelViews[" + indexStr + "].TransferOptions[0].StartDate']").rules("remove", "required");
            $("[name='TransferModelViews[" + indexStr + "].TransferOptions[0].FlightNo']").rules("remove", "required");
        }
    });
```